# update the value with iterate on Array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I would like to update the stautent status in array list. I would like update status with loop thought the arraylist.
How can I update the status in array list? Now I update all value when the 1st value is updated.

Now I have a list

```
[
{
            "studentId": 3,
            "result": 100,
            "resultStatus": false,
},
{
            "studentId": 2,
            "result": 20,
            "resultStatus": false,
},
{
            "studentId": 2,
            "result": 51,
            "resultStatus": false,
}
]


    
    const checkstatus = (result, passScore) => {
      if(result >= passScore){
        return true; //pass
      } else{
        return false; //fail
      } 
    }

    this.list =  this.list.map(x => ({
      ...x,
      resultStatus: checkstatus(x.result, 50 )
    }))
```

Expect result is

```
[
{
            "studentId": 3,
            "result": 100,
            "resultStatus": true,
},
{
            "studentId": 2,
            "result": 20,
            "resultStatus": false,
},
{
            "studentId": 2,
            "result": 51,
            "resultStatus": true,
}
]
```

Comment: It is working as expected [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-andras-dd99zy?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.mjs).

Comment: based on the question, it seems the problem is when the first student status is updated, it updates the same status for all the students. But your code seems fine. If still you are facing the problem- you can try using simple for loop.Please define the constant as 50 since you are validating with 50 based on the code shared above and replace the hardcoded 50.

for (let idx =0;idx < this.list.length;idx++){
     if(this.list[idx].result >= 50) {
        this.list[idx].resultStatus = true;
    } else {
        this.list[idx].resultStatus = false;
    }
} Thanks

Comment: @HarishDalmia It solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
const students = [
    {
        "studentId": 3,
        "result": 100,
        "resultStatus": false,
    },
    {
        "studentId": 2,
        "result": 20,
        "resultStatus": false,
    },
    {
        "studentId": 2,
        "result": 51,
        "resultStatus": false,
    }
];

const passScore = 50;

//use map() to create a new array with updated resultStatus values for each student
const updatedStudents = students.map(student => ({
    ...student,
    //inline arrow function to check if the student's result is greater than or equal to the passScore
    resultStatus: ((result, passScore) => result >= passScore)(student.result, passScore)
}));

console.log(updatedStudents);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you doesn't need any function to calculate result status

```js
const students = [
    {
        "studentId": 3,
        "result": 100,
        "resultStatus": false,
    },
    {
        "studentId": 2,
        "result": 20,
        "resultStatus": false,
    },
    {
        "studentId": 2,
        "result": 51,
        "resultStatus": false,
    }
];

const passScore = 50;


const passed =  students.map(student=> ({...student,resultStatus:student.result >= passScore}))

console.log(passed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```